# How to include logger configuration as separate file in maven assembly

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I've got a Maven (Java) project in which I am using the Logback logger, using a file `logback.xml` to configure the logger. Currently, `logback.xml` resides in `src/main/resources`. This makes sure that when I execute the project from Eclipse, that logger configuration is automatically included in the jar file and used at runtime.

However, I also want to create a binary distribution of my project (using the assembly plugin), in which the logger configuration should be available *outside* the jar file (e.g. in a separate `conf/` directory). I'm struggling with the best way to set this up.

Including the file separately is not the issue (I can use a simple `fileSet` or `file` directive in the assembly descriptor for that), but I am unsure how I can make the assembly create a jar file for my project that does *not* include the `logback.xml` file.

The only way that I can think of is to move the file from `src/main/resources/` so it won't be included in the jar, and instead add it into the `target/` directory to make sure it is included on Eclipse's runtime classpath (and then copy it from there explicitly in the assembly descriptor). I'm reluctant to have any checked-in files in `target/` though, so was hoping there was a better way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just figured it out, rather simple really.

I fixed it by adding a configuration for the `maven-jar-plugin` to my project's pom:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <configuration>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/logback.xml</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

This makes sure that although the file is still available for Eclipse's runtime classpath (in `target/classes`), it is not included when a jar is produced for my project.

Comment: This question and answer was useful to me as it helps to point me in the right direction regarding another issue I have. However, I have one question following this which is how do you know your `xml` configuration is being picked up at runtime? Is there an (idealy) easy way to test this at runtime?